# where can I find API document for Testopia 2.5?

Tags: api, bugzilla

I have gone throw the Testopia official site. but I couldn't find the API document for testopia 2.5. where can I find it?

This link is not working. :(
http://landfill.bugzilla.org/testopia2/docs/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Testopia/Testopia.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue so I generated the docs and published them here:
http://docs.devzing.com/testopia-api/